# How to call BroadCast receiver class from the main activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i'm developing an android application which will filter out the messages from a particular number and read its message body.

I have written a class which extends to broadcast receiver as follows.

```
package com.tutecentral.restfulapiclient;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver; 
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;  
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;  

public class Filter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {  
             Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();  
             if (extras != null) {  
                 Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");  
                 if (pdus.length < 1) return;   
                 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
                 String sender = null;  
                 for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {  
                     SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);  
                     if (sender == null){  
                         sender = message.getOriginatingAddress(); //get the sender  
                     }  

                     String text = message.getMessageBody(); //get the message body  
                     Log.d("my broadcast","works");
                     //System.out.println("tsettexttt"+text);
                     if (text != null){  
                         sb.append(text);  
                     }

                     System.out.println("texttst"+text);

                  }  
                 String number = "+94716355075"; //add the number
                 abortBroadcast();
             } 
         } 


     } 

}
```

Now what i want to do is to call this class from the main activity and also get the results from this class (String text : which holds the message body) so that i can use that value for other options in the app.

I went through every stackoverflow question posted regarding this but couldn't find the answer. Please be kind enough to help me out!!

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can open your activity from the `BroadcastReceiver` passing some parameters, once the activity is open if certain parameters have been passed to this activity, call the method you want.

Hope it helps!

Edit: check this code out!

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   //Do your normal work...   

   //start activity
    Intent i = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("param","value"); //your parameter
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Sir i did not get the idea!! can you be kind enough to eloborate a bit!!